# how post files array with Go?

Tags: html, file, http, post, go

i have a form with many options to post, and post files with slice,but in Go, Request.ParseForm(),only get the first file, how should i resolve with file slice?

in html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="/homeworks" >
  {{if .success}}
    <p>flash success</p>
  {{end}}

  <div id="postform">
    本次作业标题
      <input type="text" name="title" />
      <br>
    <div class="postoption"> 
      添加项目
      <input type="text" name="option[]" />
      音频文件
      <input type="file" name="radio[]" />
      答案
      <input type="text" name="answer[]" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="提交" />
</form>
```

if i do like

```
    file,header,err:=r.FormFile("file")
    fmt.Println(header)
    if err!=nil{
        panic(err)
    }
```

it will panic no such file, how can i get files slice. if i change it to radio ,it works,but
can not get file slice.

Comment: you can try getting a `MultipartReader` for the request and then read the parts manually.  http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.MultipartReader

Comment: shouldnt it be `<input type="file" name="file" />`?

Comment: @Uriel_SVK is right. The string argument to `FormFile` is the name of the input field defined in html.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

that's finally how i deal with it, By reading *Go* source code of formfile()

```
fhs := r.MultipartForm.File["radio"]
```

fhs are the Headers of FileHeader of mutlipart .

by useing Open method, i can get the interface [file](http://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#File)

```
for i:=0;i<len(fhs);i++{
    f,err:=fhs[i].Open()
}
```

then i can do the next steps.